# How can I speed up this sql query with substring?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to speed up this working query?

I have 4 tables in my database (Area, APeriod, Data, Item).   They are setup as follows [column_name (with example)]:

Area [area_code (A102)] [Area_name (Philadelphia-Wilmington-Atlantic City, PA-NJ-DE-MD]

APeriod [period (M01)] [period_abbr (JAN)] [period_name (January)]

Item [item_code (701322)] [item_name (spaghetti and macaroni, per lb. 453.6 gm)]

Data [series_id] [year (1995)] [period (M01)] [value (0.235)] [footnote_codes]

Query Description - Determine the price ratio per pound of steak sirloin [703611] to wine, red and white table (all sizes, any origin; per 1 liter) [702311] in the Miami-FT. Lauderdale area aggregated by month and separately aggregated by years from 1995 to present.

Query Code:

```
SELECT main.year, APeriod.period_name, steak.value AS Steak, wine.value AS Wine, steak.value/wine.value AS Ratio
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT year, period FROM Data) main 
INNER JOIN APeriod ON main.period = APeriod.period
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data steak ON steak.series_id ='APU0100703611' AND main.year=steak.year AND main.period=steak.period
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data wine ON wine.series_id ='APU0400720311' AND main.year=wine.year AND main.period=wine.period
ORDER BY main.year, main.period
```

This query works but it takes the MySQL server on average 129 seconds to run this query (which i'm told is ridiculously long).
Example of return

[Showing rows 0 - 24 (209 total, Query took 137.6224 seconds.) [year: 1995 - 1997]

year period_name Steak Wine Ratio

1995    January 3.593   NULL    NULL
1995    February3.510   NULL    NULL
1995    March   3.708   NULL    NULL
1995    April   3.747   NULL    NULL
1995    May     3.462   NULL    NULL
1995    June    3.742   NULL    NULL
1995    July    3.686   4.661   0.7908174
1995    August  3.823   3.978   0.9610357
1995    Septemb 3.625   4.580   0.7914847
1995    October 3.795   4.042   0.9388916
1995    November3.509   4.760   0.7371849
1995    December3.315   4.056   0.8173077
(couldn't insert image properly, sorry)

I tried taking the substring and creating a view to help speed things up but encountered other errors which leads me to believe that I did something wrong as I am new to sql.  Is there a way to speed this up?  If so, please show me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post the tables definitions - _i.e._, the `CREATE TABLE` for each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT main.year, APeriod.period_name, steak.value AS Steak, wine.value AS Wine,
       steak.value/wine.value AS Ratio
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT year, period FROM Data) main INNER JOIN
     APeriod
     ON main.period = APeriod.period LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Data steak
     ON steak.series_id ='APU0100703611' AND
        main.year=steak.year AND
        main.period=steak.period LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Data wine
     ON wine.series_id ='APU0400720311' AND
        main.year=wine.year AND
        main.period=wine.period
ORDER BY main.year, main.period;
```

Indexes should be a big help.  I would suggest:

```
create index idx_data_year_period_series on data(year, period, seies);
create index idx_aperiod_period on aperiod(period);
```

The second of these (on `aperiod.period`) already exists if `aperiod.period` is declared either as a primary key or unique.

Comment: were would I insert this into the above query?

Comment: @GorillaTek . . . You would create the indexes and re-run the query.

Comment: WOW, what a difference.  Had to correct a few column names but after that it knocked the query down to less than a second.  Thank you very much for you help.  Hope to be that knowledgeable one day. :-)